# Haskell functions will not run

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell, I looked at a lot of resources online but I still cannot figure out why the following snippet will not run:

```
isDivisor :: Int -> Int -> Bool
  isDivisor a b =
    b % a == 0
```

The code is supposed to take two integers a and b and it needs to figure out if a is a divisor of b. Now Haskell gives me the following:

```
• In the type ‘Int -> Int -> Bool isDivisor a b’
  In a pattern type signature: Int -> Int -> Bool isDivisor a b
  In the pattern: isDivisor :: Int -> Int -> Bool isDivisor a b
```

I have no idea why this happens. If someone can explain it to me it would be great!

Edit:
Some people suggested I do the following:

```
isDivisor :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isDivisor a b =
  b % a == 0
```

Now it gives me:

```
Variable not in scope: (%) :: Int -> Bool -> Bool
```

After reading some suggestions I arrived at:

```
isDivisor :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isDivisor a b = b mod a == 0
```

It gives me:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘(a0 -> a0 -> a0) -> Int -> a1’
              with actual type ‘Int’
• The function ‘b’ is applied to two value arguments,
    but its type ‘Int’ has none
  In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘b mod a’
  In the expression: b mod a == 0
```

Comment: It's an indentation issue. By indenting the first line of the definition, the parser thinks it's a continuation of the type annotation.

Comment: But if i dont indent it gives me variable not in scope why?

Comment: Because you didn't define the `(%)` function. Are you looking for the [`mod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod) function?

Comment: Note that `mod` is **not** an infix function. To use it as such, you must enclose it in backticks `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to

```
isDivisor :: Int -> Int -> Bool isDivisor a b =
    b % a == 0
```

You can't indent the first line of the definition; it treats that line as a continuation of the annotation. `a` and `b` in the annotation are type variables, and the result definition uses undefined variables `a` and `b`.

Instead, write

```
isDivisor :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isDivisor a b = 
   b `mod` a == 0
```

(`(%)` is not defined as the modulo operator in Haskell; you are looking for the `mod` function. `%` is defined by `Data.Ratio` for use in constructing values of type `Ratio a`.)

Comment: Still gives me the same error for some reason

Comment: I edited the code but it still gives me the above error why?

Comment: @YunfeiChen The code you posted is different, and lacks the backticks.

Comment: Backticks make a function an infix operator. `mod b a` and ``b `mod` a`` are equivalent.